# Flutter not showing all Pusher events sent from debug console, and showing none sent from Laravel

Tags: laravel, flutter, pusher

I am trying to show Pusher notifications in Flutter. I've set everything up and tested it with Debug console. I've noticed that, although the console itself says that, as data, you can input

```
{ ... } or a string
```

I don't get anything if it's not a json format.

Examples that work:

- {"key": "value"},
- {"key": 123}

Examples that do not work (Pusher says that events are sent successfully):

- Test
- "Test"

Why is it that some of these work and other do not?

The goal is to have Laravel send data to Pusher and get it in Flutter, but I get nothing from Pusher since the format is probably wrong, especially because Laravel's **broadcastWith** function requires that you return an array. I've tried returning my object in an array, as well a json encoded object in an array, but nothing gets received in Flutter.

Has anyone dealt with this, and could I get it to work?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it could be a limitation of the flutter library in use. Certainly, if the Pusher debug console it showing that the events are being sent to the channel then it indicates an issue with the binding/consumption of events on the client side.
You may need to reach out to the flutter library maintainer for assistance.